# ASP.NET MVC Routing with Model Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

I have an action method in a controller that I'm calling via Ajax. The specification is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeFunction(FormCollection form)
```

This works fine without any special routing configuration.

However, if I try to use a model as the parameter instead of the FormCollection, thus:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeFunction(SomeModel model)
```

I get a 500 error because the function can't be found.

What do I need to put in the RouteConfig to get this to work?

Comment: A `500(Internal Server Error)` is because your method is throwing an exception (it has nothing to do with it not being found)

Comment: Doh! You're right. All it was was that my model didn't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Help plugin: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

When using POST I would specify signature as such:

```
#region POST
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Contact newContact)
```